# Gitlab: How can I view my staging?

Tags: debian, gitlab, staging, gitlab-ci

I have setup gitlab on my server. I have a successful build of my project using gitlab_ci.

How can I test the result of my build in the browser/How to use gitlab to test and deploy my project?

Comment: Please try to isolate a precise question, which the steps you have already taken: as it stands this is too generic to be answerable.

Comment: I setup gitlab and is working ok. I create there my project and i can push and pull. After that i build the project on gitlab-ci that returns success.My problem is how can i view the web based version of the succesfull build? i have followed this setup and is working ok!https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message or a specific step that does not appear to work? At which point? You should always put those points on questions.

Comment: Gitlab and gitlab_ci working perfectly! The problem is cannot see my project in browser to test it after a succesful build.For example how can i see the home page of my project that i created and test that is ok the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using GitLab + GitLab CI to deploy a website.

If that is the case, you must use GitLab CI to do the deployment for you.

Deployment is a very wide subject with many methods and there is not much specific about gitlab to it: if you want to auto deploy just run the test suite on GitLab CI, and then run any deployment command if the tests pass.

One possible method is to deploy with Git as described at: [Auto deployment with gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721902/auto-deployment-with-gitlab)

For static websites, one good possibility would be: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5599145-preview-render-static-html-pages-pushed-to-repos if it ever gets implemented.

In short: first learn how to deploy websites in without GitLab in a way that works for you, then just add the deployment commands to gitlab CI.

Comment: i used the gitlab ci to do the deployment and all the tests passed. My problem is how to view. I think the problem is to setup on nginx sites available. I mean to create for my repository sites-available/nameofrepository and apply in the file in which port to listen so i can see the result and apply server unix:path

Comment: In that case, make a precise question focusing on your deployment stack with the precise configurations. If you don't give precise questions on SO, people will not be able to answer you. And once you have a precise question, you are much more likely to find it answered. Also, split big questions into smaller ones to create minimal questions: this question has nothing specific about GitLab to it, so you should remove that extra entropy ;)